# Keep reference data in application memory in spring application (spring MongoRepository)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

Im working on a spring application that uses monngo db. There is some reference data in the application and I think the system would behave faster if we cached that data (rather than look it up every time).

How can I achieve this? example of one ref data data table that would be affected below:

```
public interface ApplicationDetailsRepository extends MongoRepository<ApplicationDetails, String> {
    ApplicationDetails findByApplication(String application);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the annotation `@EnableCaching` seems to work well

full details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/EnableCaching.html)

So you add `@EnableCaching` to your application config

```
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("applicationdetails")));
        return cacheManager;
    }
```

then annotate your repository method as follows:

```
public interface ApplicationDetailsRepository extends MongoRepository<ApplicationDetails, String> {
    @Cacheable("applicationdetails")
    ApplicationDetails findByApplication(String application);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom implementation of the findByApplication method like described here: [spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour)

Additionally you use a field to store your "cached" values instead of retrieving them every time from your database.